# How to save the style of button and retrive it later?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to store the current style of button,so that whenever activity is sent to background or destroyed and restarted the buttons retain the style they had last time.I know how to save and retrieve information for textviews but i have no idea how to do that for button styles, basically i am more confused about how to retrieve it.
Here is my code for setting button style:

```
case R.id.darkorange:
          for (Button currentButton : buttons) {
                currentButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.darkorange);
            }
```

Now orange can be anything purple, red, blue or green. How do i save this inforation about button and retrive it later when activity is recreated.

Comment: if all are drawable just store the `R.drawable.darkorange` which is a integer in your sharedPreferences

Comment: Thanx, i was confused about R.drawable.darkorange being integer.Now i can work it out.

Comment: Just one more questionsince color can be anyone of above listed how do i retrive the specific one from button.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like these:

**res/drawable/solid.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#0078a5"
        android:endColor="#00adee"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <padding android:left="15dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="15dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#0076a3" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@style/NiceButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Colors"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

**res/values/strings.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Buttons</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Color</string>

</resources>
```

**res/values/styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
 <style name="NiceButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/solid</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**Output:**

[image]